# Why does Firebase disappear from my project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, npm, package.json

I've noticed something quite strange. I'm working on this node app using Firebase v8.9.1, and the following two things have happened.

1. The Firebase package has disappeared from node_modules along with package.json, almost as if my application had been rolled back. The rest of my app is as I last left it.

This is the second time this has happened to me, the first time I thought it was some sort of bug and didn't mind, but today it happened once again, and I'm afraid it might keep happening.

Why does the package disappear? I didn't even close the editor (VSCode).

I'm also using React, in case that's relevant.

Thank you in advance.

This is my package.json after reinstalling firebase:

```js
{
  "name": "fastbuy1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "firebase": "8.9.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "uuid": "9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "buildDeploy": "yarn build && firebase deploy --only hosting"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Edit 1: I also realized that in my github repo the package.json does show that Firebase is installed.

Edit 2: Some more information. The last thing I did was deploy the application, and it worked all right. I left the computer for about two hours and when I came back to re deploy the application, I started to receive an auth error: "Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly." I began to search for the cause, and that's when I realized that Firebase was no longer in my json nor in the modules directory. This error persists, but I'm trying to fix it by myself, and will post another question if I can't find the answer. I hope this gives a bit more clarity to the issue.

Comment: It's really hard to give you an answer in this context. What do you mean by "happen"? When/how does it happen? Were you doing the same thing both times? I thnk you already have a pointer there, make sure that you are in sync with your source control and that it has the dependency. See if this still happens then

Comment: Hi, yeah I suppose it's hard to understand what might have happened based on the information I give. I didn't do anything I could recall explicitly. The last thing I did was deploy the application, and it worked all right. I left the computer for about two hours and when I came back to re deploy the application, I started to receive an auth error: "Your API key is invalid, please check you have copied it correctly." I began to search for the cause, and that's when I realized that Firebase was no longer in my json nor in the modules directory.